# Problem with React-Native Expo Libraries/NewAppScreen

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an issue with my React-Native mobile project.
When i run npm start, I have this error, I have no idea what it could be.

> While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen`, the
>   Haste package `react-native` was found. However the module
>   `Libraries/NewAppScreen` could not be found within the package.
>   Indeed, none of these files exist:
>
> - `D:\Master\Semestre
>     1\Mobile\Projet\InsaneFrigo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen(.native||.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
>
>   - `D:\Master\Semestre 1\Mobile\Projet\InsaneFrigo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen\index(.native||.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
>       Failed building JavaScript bundle.

My **package.json** is like :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^3.13.1",
    "node": "12.9.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: you should provide the contents of your App.js file. it seems like you are importing from `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen` - which did not exist for the react-native version that you are using in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

An import was added with autocompletion and it was enough that I delete it.
Line deleted : `import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';`